# How to set tooltip for a ListviewSubItem

Tags: c#, controls, tooltip, listviewitem

I have a ListView control in Details view as that (the view that shows the list as a grid)

```
    mListView.View = View.Details; 
    mListView.mLVSelectedObject.ShowItemToolTips = true;

    ListViewItem listViewItem = mListView.Items.Add(lValue.Name);
    listViewItem.ToolTipText = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
```

The issue is that the tooltip only shows up when the cursors is over the first listview's column but not for the rest o them. I want to know if there's anyway to make it appear "easly" ?

Comment: Are you trying to add a tooltip for the whole listview, or do you want a different tooltip for each item?

Comment: I want wnat one tooltip for each row. (The same tooltip for every subitem of a listviewitem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some research. I've solved the issue this way, but I'm still wondering if there is another way to do that avoiding EventHandlers;

```
    ToolTip     mTooltip;
    Point mLastPos = new Point(-1, -1);

    private void listview_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewHitTestInfo info    =   mLV.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

        if (mTooltip == null)
            mTooltip = new ToolTip();

        if (mLastPos != e.Location)
        {
            if (info.Item != null && info.SubItem != null)
            {
                mTooltip.ToolTipTitle = info.Item.Text;
                mTooltip.Show(info.SubItem.Text, info.Item.ListView, e.X, e.Y, 20000);
            }
            else
            {
                mTooltip.SetToolTip(mLV, string.Empty);
            }
        }

        mLastPos = e.Location;
    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you handling MouseHover instead of MouseMove ?, besides you have the "ShowItemToolTips" property, just set it to true and you're fine.

Comment: @user1803300 : It is really hard to use this function on `MouseHover`. The first problem you do not have the coordinates, you need to handle many other events and there are also unexpected errors. When I have the code completed (and it will not be normal length) I will post it here.