# Calling SetToolTip on ListView multiple times, shows no tooltip at all

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, tooltip

I am trying to use [Tooltip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to show custom details when mouse moves over listview subitems. In order to do that, I am using the method mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069137/how-to-set-tooltip-for-a-listviewsubitem). Basically, it finds the subitem under the mouse and Sets the tooltip for listview.

But I am not able to make it work. I found out if I call [tooltip.SetToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on a listview multiple times, no tooltip appears at all.

To demonstrate this, I simply create a windows forms application and dropped one listview and one tooltip control. In the form show event, I wrote:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(listView1, "Hello World");
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(listView1, "Hello");
}
```

When I do above, **no tooltip is shown at all**. When I comment one of the lines, it works just fine. I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in the framework.
As soon as you use tooltip1.SetTooltip(listView1, "Text") twice the whole ToolTip Control is broken and no ToolTip associated to any control with this ToolTip is shown anymore.
For me the only solution was to newly initialize the ToolTip before assigning it again

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(listView1, "Text");
toolTip1 = new ToolTip();
toolTip1.SetToolTip(listView1, "New Text");
```

This only happens for ListViews! For e.g. Labels, Buttons etc you can use SetToolTip over and over again.

Comment: Thank you for this information! This is terrible bug in `ToolTip` .Net Framework Component. I spent hours in investigation until found your answer. As too me it's better to execute `toolTip1.RemoveAll()` and `toolTip1.Dispose()` before creating new `ToolTip` object. It guaranties that native Win32 Tooltip handler be cleaned completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code if you want to display the tooltip text on each items of listview.

```
private void FillListView()
{
    listView1.ShowItemToolTips = true;

    ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("Item 1");
    item1.ToolTipText = item1.Text;
    listView1.Items.Add(item1);

    ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("Item 2");
    item2.ToolTipText = item2.Text;
    listView1.Items.Add(item2);

    ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("Item 3");
    item3.ToolTipText = item3.Text;
    listView1.Items.Add(item3);
}
```

Or you can iterate the listview items and set the tooltip text of listviewItems as-

```
 listView1.ShowItemToolTips = true;

 foreach (ListViewItem listViewItem in listView1.Items)
  {
        listViewItem.ToolTipText = listViewItem.Text;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I want to set *custom* tooltip for *subitems*. There is no option of setting tooltip for listview subitems.